# QT gives Undefined Reference Error when declaring function pointer

Tags: c++, qt, reference

I've been working through the source code of a new project on GitHub so that I can get more acquainted with working in a team of people in the language c++, I understand that an undefined reference error is declaring a function or variable inside another class without initializing that class first, but this error seems to be something of the contrary the sample output is as follows

```
undefined reference to `PxtoneUnitIODevice::PxtoneUnitIODevice(QObject*, pxtnService const*, mooParams const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/prinzeono/Desktop/Projects/ptcollabProject/build-ptcollab-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/src/../../ptcollab/src/editor/audio/NotePreview.cpp:92: undefined reference to `PxtoneUnitIODevice::addUnit(pxtnUnitTone*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/prinzeono/Desktop/Projects/ptcollabProject/build-ptcollab-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_GCC_64bit-Debug/src/../../ptcollab/src/editor/audio/NotePreview.cpp:95: undefined reference to `PxtoneUnitIODevice::addUnit(pxtnUnitTone*)'
/usr/bin/ld: NotePreview.o: in function `NotePreview::~NotePreview()':
```

The code in *NotePreview.cpp* is as follows

```
#include "NotePreview.h"

#include <QAudioFormat>
#include <QAudioOutput>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSettings>

#include "AudioFormat.h"
#include "NotePreview.h"
#include "PxtoneUnitIODevice.h"
#include "editor/Settings.h"

// TODO: m_unit should probably be not a member variable but an r-value passed
// to the child.
constexpr int32_t LONG_ON_VALUE = 100000000;

static PxtoneUnitIODevice *device = nullptr;
static QAudioOutput *audio = nullptr;

NotePreview::NotePreview(const pxtnService *pxtn, const mooParams *moo_params,
                         int unit_no, int clock,
                         std::list<EVERECORD> additional_events, int duration,
                         std::shared_ptr<const pxtnWoice> starting_woice,
                         int bufferSize, QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent),
      m_pxtn(pxtn),
      m_unit(nullptr),
      m_moo_state(nullptr),
      m_moo_params(moo_params) {
  if (!ChordPreview::get() || unit_no == -1) {
    m_unit = std::make_unique<pxtnUnitTone>(starting_woice);
    m_this_unit = m_unit.get();
    moo_params->resetVoiceOn(m_this_unit);
    if (unit_no != -1)
      for (const EVERECORD *e = m_pxtn->evels->get_Records();
           e && e->clock <= clock; e = e->next) {
        if (e->unit_no == unit_no) {
          moo_params->processEvent(m_this_unit, e, clock, -1, m_pxtn);
        }
      }
  } else {
    m_moo_state = std::make_unique<mooState>();
    pxtnVOMITPREPARATION prep{};
    prep.flags |= pxtnVOMITPREPFLAG_loop | pxtnVOMITPREPFLAG_unit_mute;
    prep.start_pos_sample = clock * 60 * 44100 /
                            m_pxtn->master->get_beat_clock() /
                            m_pxtn->master->get_beat_tempo();
    prep.master_volume = moo_params->master_vol;
    pxtn->moo_preparation(&prep, *m_moo_state);
    for (const EVERECORD *e = m_pxtn->evels->get_Records();
         e && e->clock <= clock; e = e->next) {
      if (e->unit_no < m_moo_state->units.size())
        moo_params->processEvent(&m_moo_state->units.at(e->unit_no), e, clock,
                                 -1, m_pxtn);
    }
    m_this_unit = &m_moo_state->units.at(unit_no);
  }

  for (const EVERECORD &e : additional_events)
    moo_params->processEvent(m_this_unit, &e, clock, -1, pxtn);
  m_this_unit->Tone_KeyOn();

  // We don't constantly reset because sometimes the audio engine forces
  // [life_count = 0] (say at the end of the sample)
  if (m_unit != nullptr) {
    std::shared_ptr<const pxtnWoice> woice = m_this_unit->get_woice();
    for (int i = 0; i < woice->get_voice_num(); ++i) {
      // TODO: calculating the life count should be more automatic.
      auto tone = m_this_unit->get_tone(i);
      tone->on_count = duration;
      tone->life_count = duration + woice->get_instance(i)->env_release;
    }
  }
  if (m_moo_state != nullptr) {
    for (auto &unit : m_moo_state->units) {
      pxtnUnitTone *u = &unit;
      std::shared_ptr<const pxtnWoice> woice = u->get_woice();
      for (int i = 0; i < woice->get_voice_num(); ++i) {
        auto tone = u->get_tone(i);
        if (u == m_this_unit || tone->on_count > 0) {
          tone->on_count = duration;
          tone->life_count = duration + woice->get_instance(i)->env_release;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (device == nullptr) {
   /*Error Here*/device = new PxtoneUnitIODevice(nullptr, m_pxtn, moo_params);
    device->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
  }

  if (m_unit != nullptr) m_unit_ids.push_back(device->addUnit(m_unit.get()));
  if (m_moo_state != nullptr) {
    for (auto &unit : m_moo_state->units)
      m_unit_ids.push_back(device->addUnit(&unit));
  }

  if (audio == nullptr) {
    audio = new QAudioOutput(pxtoneAudioFormat(), device);
    audio->setVolume(1.0);
    audio->setBufferSize(bufferSize);
    audio->start(device);
  }
}

void NotePreview::processEvent(EVENTKIND kind, int32_t value) {
  m_moo_params->processNonOnEvent(m_this_unit, kind, value, m_pxtn);
}

static EVERECORD ev(int32_t clock, EVENTKIND kind, int32_t value) {
  EVERECORD e;
  e.clock = clock;
  e.kind = kind;
  e.value = value;
  return e;
}

NotePreview::NotePreview(const pxtnService *pxtn, const mooParams *moo_params,
                         int unit_no, int clock, int pitch, int vel,
                         int bufferSize, QObject *parent)
    : NotePreview(
          pxtn, moo_params, unit_no, clock,
          {ev(clock, EVENTKIND_KEY, pitch), ev(clock, EVENTKIND_VELOCITY, vel)},
          LONG_ON_VALUE, pxtn->Woice_Get(EVENTDEFAULT_VOICENO), bufferSize,
          parent) {}

NotePreview::NotePreview(const pxtnService *pxtn, const mooParams *moo_params,
                         int unit_no, int clock, int duration,
                         std::list<EVERECORD> additional_events, int bufferSize,
                         QObject *parent)
    : NotePreview(pxtn, moo_params, unit_no, clock, additional_events, duration,
                  pxtn->Woice_Get(EVENTDEFAULT_VOICENO), bufferSize, parent){};

NotePreview::NotePreview(const pxtnService *pxtn, const mooParams *moo_params,
                         int unit_no, int clock,
                         std::list<EVERECORD> additional_events, int bufferSize,
                         QObject *parent)
    : NotePreview(pxtn, moo_params, unit_no, clock, LONG_ON_VALUE,
                  additional_events, bufferSize, parent){};

NotePreview::NotePreview(const pxtnService *pxtn, const mooParams *moo_params,
                         int pitch, int vel, int duration,
                         std::shared_ptr<const pxtnWoice> woice, int bufferSize,
                         QObject *parent)
    : NotePreview(pxtn, moo_params, -1, 0,
                  {ev(0, EVENTKIND_KEY, pitch), ev(0, EVENTKIND_VELOCITY, vel)},
                  duration, woice, bufferSize, parent) {}

NotePreview::~NotePreview() {
  /*Error Here*/for (const auto &id : m_unit_ids) device->removeUnit(id);
}
```

The code in *PxtoneUnitIODevice.h* is as follows

```
#ifndef PXTONEUNITIODEVICE_H
#define PXTONEUNITIODEVICE_H
#include <QIODevice>
#include <map>

#include "pxtone/pxtnService.h"
#include "pxtone/pxtnWoice.h"

/* An IO device for playing audio from a number of custom units separately from
 * the moo stream. It's not just a single unit because multiplexing and having
 * one audio output continuously playing is significantly faster on Windows.
 */
class PxtoneUnitIODevice : public QIODevice {
  Q_OBJECT

 public:
  PxtoneUnitIODevice(QObject *parent, const pxtnService *pxtn,
                     const mooParams *moo_params);
  void removeUnit(int unit_id);
  int addUnit(pxtnUnitTone *unit);
  virtual ~PxtoneUnitIODevice() { close(); };

 signals:
  void MooError();

 private:
  std::map<int, pxtnUnitTone *> m_units;
  const pxtnService *m_pxtn;
  const mooParams *m_moo_params;
  int m_next_unit_id;
  qint64 readData(char *data, qint64 maxlen);
  qint64 writeData(const char *data, qint64 len);
};

#endif  // PXTONEUNITIODEVICE_H
```

What I would like to know is why I am getting this error, and possibly how to fix it

Comment: Well, you show where `PxtoneUnitIODevice` constructor and `addUnit` are declared. Are they actually implemented somewhere? It's the missing implementation the linker's complaining about.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik   Yes it is implemented

Comment: Well, the linker believes differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to tell QT to use the latest version, problem is solved